# Webpage doesn't recognize a mobile device and adjust the display

Tags: css

All,
I've got the following webpage:
http://www.okynemedialab.com/gear_checkout.php

I'm trying to display this on my mobile device (iPhone) and it doesn't seem to recognize that I'm using a mobile device. I have the following bit of CSS to control the max-width:

```
/* Optimized for Tablets */
@media (max-width: 800px) { 
    #featured, #main, #bottom { font-size:10px; }
}
/* Optimized for Mobile Devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #wrapper {padding:0;}
    #main { font-size:9px; float:none; margin:0 0 10px 0; width:100%;}
}
```

I call this CSS by using the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<?php echo $url; ?>gear.css" type="text/css" />
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't adjust. I do have some tables that get prepopulated and then hidden with some jQuery but I don't have widths on them so that shouldn't be the issue. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work for me on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer for a similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454294/1521179

(searching can help...)

The problem is that iOS devices have a pseudo-width of circa 1000px. The linked answer shows how to work around that.